# Can a president be evicted from the White House?

Tags: united-states

Currently, there are impeachment investigations going on for the POTUS. Lets say the POTUS is formally impeached and Trump is removed from office. However Trump refuses to leave the White House on claims that the "witch hunt" impeachment is false and not legally valid. Is it possible to remove the President from the White House by force?

Comment: Yes, but then they'd have to forgive him his trespasses. That's a commandment, it takes more than 2/3 of Congress to override it!

Comment: I've edited you question to try and improve the English.  If you don't like the edits feel free to roll them back.  If I have misunderstood your question, roll back my edits, and clarify the question please!

Comment: There is a [similar question concerning refusal to accept election results](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/41222/6927) at [Politics.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Senate has convicted by the necessary majority, Trump would no longer be the President - Mike Pence would be.  There is no legal difficulty in removing ordinary citizens from the White House.

Of course, President Pence might decide that he didn't mind ex-President Trump remaining in the White House, and I think the law enforcement agencies would be obliged to respect that.

Comment: Is the White House exempt from the DC landlord-tenant law? Is POTUS a tenant? Who is the landlord?

Comment: One can evict a trespasser as well as a tenant (at least in England and Wales).  I am pretty sure POTUS is *not* a tenant and hence landlord-tenant law doesn't apply to the White House.

Comment: @user6726 In general, landlord-tenant laws in the US don't apply to employee housing provided for the convenience of the employer. Even if DC's laws did apply, the United States is generally immune from DC law.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a question for Politics SE. In your proposed situation, the Secret Service would remove him without issue. But I'm not sure this would legally count as an "eviction".

Comment: Yea, the question in its original for was regarding the "trespassing" legality of it.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic here.  (It might be on-topic on Politics too.)

Comment: "Evict" can mean "to recover by legal process", but I wasn't using that meaning in my edit to the question.  It can also mean "to force out".  See. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evict @Digitalfire If you think my edit hasn't captured your question, **please** edit the question again.